# Update nested react state object with new arbitrary object

Tags: reactjs

How can I update a value within a react state object when that value is an object? Example:

```
this.state = { nestedObj: { x: 0, y: 5 } };
```

at a later time, I want to update that nestedObj with an arbitrary object based on the object created from a `JSON.parse` based on user input.

I try the following and it does not work:

```
const newObj = {nestedObj: { x: 0, arbitraryKey: 'bla', anotherOne: { h: 0 }}};
this.setState(newObj);
```

I would really like to just blow away whatever object resides at `this.state.nestedObj` and replace it with whatever object is defined at `newObj`. How can I do that? I have other keys in my `this.state` so it would be ideal if this only affected the `nestedObj` but I'm not super picky.
Thanks!

Comment: did you tried `this.setState({nestedObj: newObj})`?

Answer (score 3):

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      obj: {a: 'hello', b: 'world'}
    };
  }
 
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('obj is initialized to: ', this.state.obj);
  }
 
  handleClick = () => {
 const value = Math.random().toFixed(2);
 this.setState({
  obj: {a: value, b: value}
 }, () => console.log('obj is changed to: ', this.state.obj));
  };

  render() {
 return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>button</button>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Main />, 
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```